# How to know if a tag is rendered in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular6, openlayers

I have this code in an Angular app when I want to load several maps using Open Layers:

```
<div *ngFof="let map of maps">
    <map id="{{ 'map' + map.id }}" class="map"></map>
</div>
```

In my component, when I try to get this map by id (the target) seem that map tag is no already ready so the map is no showed.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.mapService.getMaps().subscribe(
        resp => {
            this.maps = resp;
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.maps.forEach(item => {
       let map = new ol.Map({
       target: 'map' + item.id,
       layers: [
           new ol.layer.Tile({
               source: new ol.source.OSM()
           })
       ],
       view: new ol.View({
           center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]),
           zoom: 2
           })
       });

       this.maps.push(map);
   });
}
```

I have tried several solutions I have seen googling but I cannot do my code run so when map is created (`new ol.Mapl(...)`) the tag `map` is not already rendered.

Comment: Maybe the ngAfterViewInit is been executed before than the getmaps suscriptions emit the maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue using `ViewChild` and `ngAfterViewInit`:

```
@ViewChild('map') mapViewChild: ElementRef;
```

And

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.map.setTarget(this.target);
}
```

So I initialize the map in `onInit` function and set the tag target in the `ngAfterViewInit` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `getMaps` subscription fires after the `ngAfterViewInit` code, at that time the `maps` variable would be empty.

Try putting your for loop after you assign the values to maps.

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.mapService.getMaps().subscribe(
     resp => {
         this.maps = resp;

         this.maps.forEach(item => {
            let map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map' + item.id,
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                })
            ],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]),
                zoom: 2
                })
            });

           this.maps.push(map);
       });
    },
    error => {
        console.log(error);
    }
  );
}
```

One other issue i see that you expand the `maps` array in the `forEach` loop.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it... but seem that maps are created before <map> is rendered in the template.

Comment: Try executing the `forEach` inside a setTimeout, with 50ms timeout.